# How to extract data associated to a table of content from word document using VBA code

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

How to iterate through each and every heading name in (table of contents) and extract their associated data content (both text & non text ) from word document using VBA ?

[image]

For example, consider attached picture,  how will I be able to extract the  data contents (arrows pointed to the required 3 data contents) corresponding to a specific heading name "4.1.7.3 Description of Roles "?

In the attached picture , list of headings(table of contents) are displayed in the left panel, when we click on any specific toc item then it's corresponding data will be displayed in the right panel/section.

Currently, I am able access each heading content with below provided code .

Please guide me on how to extract their associated data content ( both text & non text ) with VBA code.

```
Sub Main()
        Dim strFile As String
        Dim oWord As Word.Application
        Dim oWdoc As Word.Document
        Dim oPar As Word.Paragraph
        Dim rng As Word.Range
        strFile = "C:\Users\SQVA\Desktop\My_Work\MyTest3.docx"
        'Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        Set oWord = New Word.Application
        Set oWdoc = oWord.Documents.Open(strFile)
        Call Get_Heading_Name(oWord, oWdoc, strFile, rng)
        Call Close_Word(oWord, oWdoc)
    End Sub


 Sub Get_Heading_Name(oWord As Word.Application, oWdoc As Word.Document, strFile As String, rng As Word.Range)
    oWord.Visible = True
    Dim astrHeadings As Variant
    Dim strText As String
    Dim intItem As Integer
    Set rng = oWdoc.Content
    astrHeadings = _
    oWdoc.GetCrossReferenceItems(wdRefTypeHeading)
    For intItem = LBound(astrHeadings) To UBound(astrHeadings)
        strText = Trim$(astrHeadings(intItem))
            Debug.Print CStr(strText)
    Next intItem
End Sub

Sub Close_Word(oWord As Word.Application, oWdoc As Word.Document)
        oWdoc.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
        oWord.Quit
        Set oWdoc = Nothing
        Set oWord = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Please describe in detail what uniquely identifies the "highlighted content" and what you want to do with it. At this point, we can only guess what you have in mind - I have no desire to spend my time guessing and have you tell me, no, that's not what you meant.

Comment: Hi Cindy, currently my client have application related requirements like user specific  requirements (URS) and functional specific requirements (frs) in word documents ,they want me write a automated solution which will automatically read the requirements from word document and create the same content in HP ALM as requirement entities with parent and child heirarchy, for this purpose I need to know how to extract the highlighted  contents from word document,I want to repeat the process one by one with all the requirements present on word document and then create them in HP ALM requirements.

Comment: What is needed is a *technical* explanation. You have a TOC and can access it - fine. What else needs to be done *technically*? You see what your client has, structurally - I don't. You know what the end result needs to be, structurally, and how it relates to what the client already has - I don't. I can't help without that kind of information. Look at what you've provided as if you've never seen it before and ask yourself what you'd need *us* to tell *you* if you were in our place. And please add this to the question using the [edit] link, not in comments.

Comment: Thanks for assistance Cindy, I reframed question as advised.

Comment: Your reframed question is hardly any clearer - I see no highlighting. From your problem description, what you're asking might be achieved by copying & pasting the entire document.

Comment: Macropod, I reframed question once again. I want to do copy paste automatically , please let me know of you need any clarification

Comment: As this is Stack Overflow we have a bit of a problem: as it stands your question is too broad. I'm not adverse to helping you, if you have the patience to let me lead you through to finding the approach and we break this up into "bite-sized pieces". If you were an end-user and had to do this manually, how would you START to go about it, given you're looking at the TOC entry?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt response Cindy.if I am an end-user  first I will open the word document,then I will set the word document mode to navigation ,In the navigation content that is displayed in the left panel I  will choose(click on) the navigation list item for which data has to be extracted. then manually I will copy the heading index,heading name,non text and text contents under that specific heading. If the chosen navigation list item has sub list or children then the same process of navigating to that sub list item and then extracting similar details will be performed manually.

Comment: Hi Cindy & macropod , I am able to get list of all heading names ( updated question content with my latest code), Now, for each heading name, could you please help me on how to extract their associated data content